# How to loop through all controls and get its id and values in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have 10 buttons in my Main Activity area, and I want to loop through all the controls and check if that control is a button and finally extract its values and id.

I have tried looping through 10 and getting each id but I have to name my buttons like button1, button2...., the problem is naming buttons like this will be troublesome in future use.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("button_"+i, "id", getPackageName());
    button[i] = findViewById(id);
}
```

In VB.NET you can execute this task by:

```vbs
For Each Con As Control In Me.Controls
   If Con.GetType Is GetType(Button)
       //code here
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the child view from the layout with `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` then check if the View is an instance of a Button. Something like this:

```
// assuming this is your parent layout
LinearLayout llyParent = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

Button[] button = new Button[10];

// then you can iterate for each child view inside the layout
int count = llyParent.getChildCount();

// count the last position of the button
int lastPosition = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   // get the child View
   View view = llyParent.getChildAt(i);

   // then check if it an instance of a Button
   if (view instanceof Button) {
      button[lastPosition] = (Button) view;

      // increment the position for the next button.
      lastPosition++;
   }

}
```